# Pourquoi ajoutons-nous une négation dans « Cela fait longtemps qu'on ne s'est pas rencontrés ! » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, indications-de-temps

Lorsque nous nous exclamons :

> Cela fait longtemps qu'on ne s'est pas rencontrés...

Ou dans bien d'autres phrases similaires comme :

> Ça fait bien trop longtemps qu'on n'a pas vu ce film !

Le français ajoute une négation autour du verbe. Pourquoi ceci et d'où cela vient-t-il ? Dans la phrase, cela fait longtemps qu'on ne s'est pas rencontrés, nous pourrions comprendre que ça fait effectivement très longtemps qu'on ne s'est PAS rencontrés, et donc qu'on se rencontre constamment, comme notamment, en ce moment.

Pourquoi ne pas dire : « Cela fait longtemps qu'on s'est rencontrés » ?
C'est d'ailleurs ainsi que s'expriment les anglophones :

```
It's been a while since we met!
```

Aucune négation !

Comment: Question répondue par l'académie française : http://www.academie-francaise.fr/mounia-b

Comment: Les anglophones disent aussi "We haven't met for a really long time," qui est plus proche du français.

Comment: Les deux langue font les choses différement, mais pour moi c'est l'anglais qui est moins clair. "It's been a while since we met" pourrait vouloir dire : on s'est rencontré il y longtemps, c'est à dire : on se connaît depuis longtemps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> - *Pourquoi ne pas dire : « Cela fait longtemps qu'on s'est rencontrés » ?*

Parce que le message exprimé serait ambigu.

Si l'on souhaite évoquer notre dernière rencontre et indiquer qu'elle s'est déroulée il y a longtemps, on dira :

> La dernière fois qu'on s'est rencontrés, c'était il y a longtemps.

et si l'on insiste sur la longueur de la période sans rencontre :

> Depuis la dernière fois qu'on s'est rencontrés, il s'est passé/écoulé beaucoup de temps.

En revanche, dans la phrase :

> Ça fait longtemps qu'on **ne s'est pas** rencontrés.

le message principal concerne **l'absence de rencontre** (d'ou la négation), absence qui dure depuis longtemps.

La phrase suggérée sur le modèle de l'anglais :

> Cela fait longtemps qu'on s'est rencontrés.

n'exclut pas le fait que l'on puisse s'être rencontrés depuis.

Si quelqu'un dit, « avec ma femme, ça fait longtemps qu'on s'est rencontrés », on ne va pas penser qu'ils ne sont plus ensemble.

On pourra donc préciser soit :

> On s'est rencontrés il y a longtemps. (n'exclut pas l'absence de rencontre depuis)

soit

> On s'est rencontrés **pour la dernière fois** il y a longtemps. (exclut d'autres rencontres depuis)

---

> - *Dans la phrase, cela fait longtemps qu'on ne s'est pas rencontrés, nous pourrions comprendre que ça fait effectivement très longtemps qu'on ne s'est PAS rencontrés, et donc qu'on se rencontre constamment, comme notamment, en ce moment.*

Cette interprétation n'est guère plausible. Une rencontre étant un événement ponctuel, on peut difficilement « se rencontrer constamment » ou alors on dira :

> Ça fait longtemps qu'on arrête pas de se rencontrer.

dont la négation est :

> Ça fait longtemps qu'on a arrêté de se rencontrer tout le temps...

Note: [Réponse de l'Académie à cette question](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/mounia-b).

Comment: Comment expliquez-vous qu'en anglais on dise : "It's been a while since we met", ce qui contredit une partie de l'argumentation de votre réponse ?

Comment: Je ne perçois pas de contradiction. *It's been a while **since we met*** signifie "Il s'est écoulé pas mal de temps [ ou "Beaucoup de temps a passé"] **depuis qu'on s'est rencontrés**" voire, en français bancal, "ça fait longtemps depuis qu'on s'est rencontrés". En français comme en anglais, la négation n'a guère de sens dans ce type de phrase : "Le temps a passé depuis qu'on ne s'est pas rencontré ??"

Answer (score 1):

En anglais l'utilisation de « since » (depuis) change les rapports entre les mots; il est utilisé pour apporter un point de référence dans le passé et le déroulement de l'action est considéré à ce point particulier comme étant la dernière occurrence (par convention). En français on ne se base pas sur un point de référence mais sur une période de référence (longtemps), ce qui correspond à la période depuis le point de référence spécifié par « since ». Le déroulement de l'action est considéré comme une occurrence pendant cette période (par convention) et comme il n'y en a aucune la négation s'impose. Donc la construction est logique. Il faut bien faire attention de considérer « longtemps » comme une période et de ne pas déduire de son emploie avec « depuis » qu'il indique un point dans le passé; il ne fait cela qu'implicitement.

([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+rencontr%C3%A9+depuis+longtemps%2Cpas+rencontr%C3%A9s+depuis+longtemps&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20rencontr%C3%A9%20depuis%20longtemps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20rencontr%C3%A9s%20depuis%20longtemps%3B%2Cc0), [ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+vu+depuis+longtemps&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20vu%20depuis%20longtemps%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpas%20vu%20depuis%20longtemps%3B%2Cc0)) « Nous ne nous sommes pas rencontrés depuis longtemps. » contient un vice sémantique solidement installé dans le langage et qui tend à introduire de fausses notions : c'est le mot « depuis » qui est mal utilisé comme il ne signifie plus « en partant d'un point donné dans le passé » (spécifié par un terme après « depuis » dans la phrase), mais « pendant une période donnée ».

Comment: Je trouve votre analyse assez fine, en particulier sur la déformation imposée au mot "longtemps" comme un point temporel et non comme une durée. Je pense que l'astuce très sournoise de la mauvaise formulation se trouve là.

Answer (score 0):

Nous avons tous été élevés dans le culte de la langue française, de sa prétendue clarté et de la beauté de ses complexités. Las, il en est parfois autrement et votre question en est une bonne illustration.

Le « ne » ambigu que vous trouvez avec de nombreux verbes n'est pas de négation mais est dit **explétif**. Il ne remplit ni fonction sémantique ni grammaticale et peut être supprimé sans altérer le sens. Comme l'explique par exemple l'Académie française [ici](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/gilles-r-france), il s'agit d'un reste de langue latine, anomalie cultivée au fil du temps par les écrivains pour des raisons de prosodie ou de métrique.
Les meilleurs grammairiens peinent beaucoup à justifier l'existence de cette bizarrerie. Voir par exemple l'[article de Michel Francard](https://www.lesoir.be/art/1511453/article/debats/chroniques/vous-avez-ces-mots/2017-05-26/ne-expletif-d-autant-plus-beau-qu-il-est-inutile) (linguiste de renom).

Ce n'est pas le seul cas :

— *Il y a trois guichets d'ouverts* : le *d'* (de) est explétif.

— *Qu'est-ce qu'il m'a bricolé là ?* : le *m'* (à moi) est explétif, à vocation dite phatique (renforcement du discours).
Il est donc souvent un peu vain de décortiquer la phrase pour trouver à toute fin une subtilité de sens que la première lecture ne livre pas…

Comment: Un *ne* peut être explétif mais ce n'est pas le cas de *ne ... pas* qui dénote toujours une négation. Je vois mal comment la question pourrait être une bonne illustration de l’ambiguïté qu'apporte le *ne explétif* alors qu'elle n'en contient pas.

Comment: Je comprends votre perplexité : le "ne" n'est en effet pas ici directement explétif comme dans la tournure "je crains qu'il (ne) vienne". Mais sa suppression ne change pas non plus le sens de la phrase. Sans doute est-ce la subtilité pointée par LPH, correspondant à la nuance anglaise entre "since" et "for". Je reconnais humblement ne pas pouvoir mieux décortiquer ce paradoxe.

Comment: Ces *ne* ne sont ni directement, ni indirectement explétifs. Les deux phrases de la question utilisent des négations claires. Je ne vois pas où il y aurait un paradoxe. Supprimer le **ne** en laissant le **pas** comme le fait le français parlé maintient la négation. Supprimer la négation complète change le sens de la phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Pour lever l’ambiguïté entre première rencontre et la dernière rencontre ayant eu lieu, pourquoi ne pas dire : it’s been a while since we LAST met” ?

Comment: Cela ne répond pas à la question !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22021)